# Picking random colors without repeatingly finding the excluded ones

Tags: android, random

There is a MxM square matrix.  Each two elements have the same colors in the matrix. For example, in a 2x2 matrix, there will be 2 blacks and 2 reds. The aim is to distribute colors randomly. The problem with the algorithms I checked so far is that they pick a random number in a range with excluded numbers but they keep to find that random number until the found number is not equal to the excluded ones. So in this process, generated number may be equal to excluded numbers indefinite times until the correct number found. Could you give me a better idea?

Comment: indefinite is highly improbable, but OK. You could use an indirection table. You only pick a random index and use the colour it points to. If you don't want to reuse that colour, eliminate it from the table. Of course, if you want to pick one out of 4 million colours, with a few forbidden ones, it is cheaper to accept a miss.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem - you have to fill matrix with known elements placed randomly so:

- Convert matrix to the array
- Fill array with colors (in some non-random way)
- Permute array